# Accidently removed HDD in sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sleep

I have a PC with 2 disks:
- SSD-disk with windows 7 on it 
- HDD-disk with some my stuff and pagefile.sys
So i shutdown pc in sleep mode and removed HDD (non-system partition with pagefile.sys) for some purposes. After that i accidentally turned on computer and pressed sleep mode again and got an BSOD.
After that i've tried repair tool. It didnt help at all. I don't have restore points. Any back ups.
But have second OS Ubuntu (if it can provide any help).
If i run it in a safe mode, it stops loading on CLASSPNP.sys

So, what possibly can go wrong with hot non-system disk remove?
I ran out of ideas. Pls help.

Comment: Will it boot with just the SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i restore registry.

- Enter Repair Tool
- Go to command console (last item)
- Type "notepad"
- Go to %windows folder%/system32/config/
- Enter * (asterisk) in filensme field (it will show hidden files)
- Rename SOFTWARE and SYSTEM files (so we can restore them if it not helps)
- Go to /RegBack folder and copy SOFTWARE and SYSTEM files to replace renamed

After that i managed to load normally